Spring boot 3: micrometer, zipkin, prometeus
I have pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-sender-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>

So, micrometer create traceId, send it to kafka topic and zipkin get it from kafka topic.
But in prometheus I have an error:
metric name http_server_requests_seconds_count does not support exemplars
It worked in spring-boot 2.x. And work if exclude zipkin and brave dependencies.

Which version of prometheus are you using? Is this issue related to your case? https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/issues/407

@mrq version is 2.40.1

Fist of all, please do not define versions that are defined by Boot, also micrometer-tracing is pulled in by micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave so you can delete the micrometer-tracing dependency from your POM.
It seems you are using an unsupported version of Prometheus server. Exemplars support for all time series was added in #11982. It was released in Prometheus 2.43.0, please upgrade.
If you want to hack this (please don't and use a supported version of Prometheus instead), If you create a SpanContextSupplier @Bean that always says isSampled false and it returns null for the spanId and traceId, you will not see those exemplars.
In Spring Boot 3.3.0 and Micrometer 1.13.0, we added support to the Prometheus 1.x Java Client which supports conditionally enabling exemplars on all time series (i.e.: _count), see PrometheusConfig in Micrometer so that you can disable this.

After update Prometheus version, all works fine, Thanks!
